# Lighting Up A Room Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, effects

Is it possible to simulate a candle for instance in cocos2d. So the scene will be black and then when the candle appears it will lighten up the room in a realistic way.

If possible, how would I achieve that effect? Any redirections, guidance is welcome.

Thanks.

Please note, that I don't want light reflection algorithms, as this is only for simple use. I just need it for a game where the players life is the abillity to see the room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out raycasting. If you set up Cocos2d to use Box2d, you can use Box2d's raycasting method to achieve this effect. You can make the walls in your room box2d rigid-bodies, and then raycast from your candle origin to a number of points on a circle around it. If the raycast intersects a wall, mark the location of the intersection. Then at the end you can fill in the area with light that is inside a polygon created by all of the raycast intersection points.

Comment: Do you know if you can get the distance for the raycast intersection? Because that would be needed to simulate a light, Hence objects far away shouldn't be lighten up as much as those that are close.

Comment: @Chrene You can read a good tutorial on Box2d raycasting on [raywendelich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4653/intermediate-box2d-physics-forces-ray-casts-and-sensors). The raycast callback stores several pieces of information in the ReportFixture method -- including the intersection **point** b2Vec2. Just if you know the point of origin of the raycast, you can easily calculate the distance between the origin and this intersection point.